# Converting Timestamp to Date gives different timezones in the result?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I have a database where I have put down timestamps that are converted to UTC.

Now, when I am on PST, I convert 2 timestamps in Chrome, which get back to the following dates:

```
  new Date(1446274800000)
```

Sat Oct 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

```
  new Date(1448265600000)
```

Mon Nov 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

They differ in  timezone! How is this possible? I always just want to get back the PST time (or, preferably, the UTC time they were stored in).

Comment: "They differ in timezone" - no, they differ in abbreviation and offset. Both are in Pacific time, which is the time zone you're in. "PST" is only "Pacific Standard Time" - over the summer, assuming you were in the same time zone, you were observing PDT (Pacific Daylight Time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's [daylight savings time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379922/how-does-javascript-know-the-time-zone-of-a-date-in-milliseconds).